# Find all algebras and $\sigma$-algebra of $\{A \subset X: x \in A\}$ where $x$ fixed point in $X$

Tags: measure-theory

Find all algebras and $\sigma$-algebras of $\{A \subset X: x \in A\}$ where $x$ is fixed point in $X$.

**Attempt**

$\mathscr{A}=\{ \emptyset, X, \{x\}, X \setminus \{x\} \}$. But I don't know how construct more or prove there are no more sets.

Comment: Is $\emptyset$ allowed here?

Comment: Yes, because X is here ($X \subset X$ such that $x \in X$). Then I want that $\mathscr{A}$ will be an algebra ($\sigma$-algebra) then complements must be in $\mathscr{A}$, so $X^{c}=\emptyset \in \mathscr{A}$

Comment: I am just a bit confused. Isn't the empty set not a member of $\{ A\subset X :x\in A\}$? What do you mean by algebra of $\{ A\subset X :x\in A\}$?

Comment: I want to describe algebra and $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{A \subset X : x \in A\} \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$.
$\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ is an algebra if $\emptyset \in \mathscr{A}$, closed under finite unions, and closed under complements

Comment: If you want to find the algebra generated by a subset $\mathscr Y$ of the power set, that algebra would at least contain $\mathscr Y$. So it is not true that it has only four elements.

Comment: Exactly, thats my problem. How can I describe all those subsets?

Answer (score 2):

The sigma algebra generated by a collection of sets is the minimal sigma algebra containing all those sets. Your attempt is therefore incorrect as it does not contain all members of $\{A\subset X:x\in A\}$.

Hint: Can you find a set $A\subset X$ such that $x\notin A$ and $x\notin A^{c}$.

Comment: I think no. suppose exists that $A$. But if $x \notin A$, then $x \in A^{c}$, contradiction.

Comment: Precisely! So what can you say about the set $A$, must it be in your sigma algebra? What does this imply?

Comment: Then $A$ is not in my algebra. So, the algebra does not exist. Am I right?

Comment: No! We agreed to the fact that if I give you a subset $A\subset X$ then either $x\in A$ or $x\in A^{c}$. So then either $A\in \{B\subset X: x\in B\}$ or $A^{c}\in \{B\subset X: x\in B\}$. From this, what can you say about $A$, must it be in your $\sigma$-algebra (it helps to think what axioms $\sigma$ algebra must satisfy)

Comment: So te generated of $\{A \subset X : x \in A\}= \mathscr{P}(X)$

Comment: Yes! That is correct